# Откуда загружается скрипт при логине пользователя в домен

Tags: сервер, windows-10, windows-server-2012, group-policy

Групповыми политиками сделал запуск скрипта при логине пользователей.
Почему-то у некоторых пользователей мой скрипт накладывается на старый скрипт.

Выглядит это так: логинюсь на компе, где этот пользователь не логинился еще, на рабочем столе срабатывает мой скрипт, потом срабатывает еще какой-то, и информация накладывается друг на друга.
Что мне известно:
- это дело не в каком-то конкретном компе, потому что под другими пользователями на том же компе всё ок.
- в групповых политиках нет ничего похожего, кроме моего скрипта.
- когда логинится "странный" пользователь, то эта фигня откуда-то подгружается.
- в Active Directory в профилях скриптов нет.
- rsop.msc кроме моего скрипта ничего не показывает.
- перезаливка винды не поможет, потому что загружается при логине определенных пользователей.
- в реестре локального компа в Run и RunOnce нет.

Есть идеи, куда еще могли напихать, или подскажите места в реестре в Windows откуда может загружаться?
Пока только понятно по виду, что это из семейства bginfo.
Что заметил: политик в консоли на контроллере меньше чем в SYSVOL\domain\policies

Спасибо.

[image: Рабочий стол]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И оказалось это в C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
А в реестре не было...